# High frequency sound and unwanted shutdowns

Tags: mac-mini, shutdown

My Mac-Mini (april 2020) makes a high frequency noise, it doesn't always occur and never after a reboot.

Probably this kind of noise :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_acoustic_noise

A bigger problem is when using any software (drawing or coding or just when the computer is idle,) my Mac Mini turns off randomly (not every day) and I need to unplug it to reboot.

I call Apple, make a diagnostic and go to an Apple premium reseller. No problems found. :(

Any ideas ?

Comment: Well, two likely sources for a high pitched sound: 1) is a bearing (so a fan...) or 2) a failing capacitor can make noises... and not sure a software diagnostic will pick up either.